# Find limit of function with absolute values in the nominator

Tags: limits

Im having trouble finding this limit because of the absolute value signs. I tried to split the function in 2 and find their limits separately but without any luck.

I also tried to see if I found the same limit when x approaching 0 from the left and right side, but my answer is nothing near the correct one. Im guessing there's something im ignoring completely here. Ether way, here it is:

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{|3x-1| - |3x+1| }{x}$

Any help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about how each absolute value behaves when $x$ is sufficiently close to $0$. In particular, suppose that $x \in (\frac{-1}{3}, \frac{1}{3})$. Then observe that $|3x - 1| = -3x + 1$ and $|3x + 1| = 3x + 1$. Hence, we obtain:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(-3x + 1) - (3x + 1)}{x}
= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{-6x}{x}
= \lim_{x\to 0} -6
= -6
$$

Comment: I understood it now, thanks!